# How to make datatable responsive in .coffee file (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have datatable displaying pretty well, but I would like them to be responsive for mobile viewing.

I tried the adding the `responsive:true` option, but it does not change anything.

```
jQuery ->
  $("#eventmanagment").dataTable({
    "searching": true
    "responsive": true
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]]
  })
  $("#eventmanagmentone").dataTable({
    "searching": true
    "limit": 5
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]]

  })
```

The table should fold down as the user shrinks the window or uses a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add javascript and css file for enable to responsive feature work in datatables

this is a [link](https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/) for getting those file

after add css and javascript file you need to enable a responsive feature.

```
"responsive": true
```

the working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sayedrafeeq/qdg0n188/)

> responsive datatable extension library

```
css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.jqueryui.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap4.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.dataTables.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.semanticui.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.jqueryui.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.foundation.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.foundation.css
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/css/responsive.semanticui.css
js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.semanticui.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.jqueryui.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap4.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.dataTables.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.foundation.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.semanticui.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.foundation.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.js
//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.2/js/responsive.jqueryui.js
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. Do we need to add these 30 files ?

Comment: no use only those file which extension you need. if you want to use responsive then only use responsive.js and responsive.css